# Checking if a text on a label exists in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

Can somebody help me with this?

I am adding the text of a label into a datagridview. But before i do the insert, i want to check if the text does not already exist in the datagridview. I am stack. Need help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop through the rows and cells of the `DataGridView` and compare the strings, something like:

```
Private Sub AddLabelToDGV(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal labelText As String)
    Dim found As Boolean = False
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
        For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
            If cell.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso cell.Value.ToString().Equals(labelText) Then
                found = True ' if this is found it might be worth exiting the loop now instead of continuing
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If Not found Then
        Dim row As New DataGridViewRow
        row.CreateCells(dgv)
        row.Cells(0).Value = labelText
        dgv.Rows.Add(row)
    End If
End Sub
```